# How do I keep IE8 from using compatibility mode to render my page?

Tags: ie8-compatibility-mode

Is there another means of keeping IE8 from deciding to render my page in compatibility mode?
I know I can add the `x-ua-compat` meta tag to my pages, but I'd rather not do that just to make IE stop complaining about an otherwise standards compliant and valid page.

Comment: Do you have a page you can show us so we can see if there's something else at hand that's causing IE8 to go into compatibility mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

is supposed to make it standards compliant.